# Gnome calendar asks credentials for public ical

Tags: gnome, evolution, calendar

I am using ubuntu 18.10. When I tried to add [this](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/k23j233gtcvau7a8ulk2p360m4%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics) public ical to gnome-calendar from here [image: ical_adding_wizard]

then this appeared [image]

this is a public ical address and it should not require password. In ubuntu 16.04 it worked without any credentials. Which username and password should I enter here?

Comment: What happens if you keep them blank and press the "Connect" button?

Comment: @pomsky Just the credential wizard disappears and nothing happens. The `add` button still remains disable.

Comment: I have got the exact same problem. Unable to add my public iCal calendar. Add button remains disabled.

Comment: much as I try to use open source software, this is the kind of basic bug which makes it impossible or very time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable calendar sharing from your Google account [here](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/syncselect).

Select the calendar you want to access with Gnome and this will update your public calendar of your Google account.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this done by using Evolution to add Google's private iCal link as calendar.

The trick is to use "On the Web", not "CalDAV".

[image]

After this is done, the calendar appears and works (albeit Read Only) in Gnome Calendar.

Comment: Yup this was the only way for gnome calendar to pick up the changes...how strange.